# How can I have different inventory for different colors for a single item?

Tags: configurable-product, product-attribute, stock, inventory, magento-2.1.3

I am working with Magento 2.1.3 and am currently trying to get my products configured on my site.

I have a few t-shirts that are available in multiple colors and I am wondering how I can get them to display on the site without appearing as "out of stock" when only one color is unavailable. (ie.. I have 70 black shirts and 0 white - same design..)

I have created product attributes that I then put into an attribute set which I then use to create a configurable product. I configure the attributes and end up with the 10 different simple products (5 sizes/2 colors). When I go to my main site, the item shows up, but displays as out of stock even though I have 70 shirts listed in the inventory.

Comment: Generally magento show up simple product on main configurable product, for your requirement you need to customized magento.